# Filtering out Java Log Statements in the Atom Editor

Tags: java, logging, filter, editor, atom-editor

I'm wondering if there exists a plugin or native support for filtering out log statements (SLF4J, Log4J, etc.) statements in the atom editor?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: The [atom] tag you used for this question is in relation to the XML based syndication format, as this post is about GitHub's Atom Editor I have changed the tag to [atom-editor]. If you are not sure about how to use tags, please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

First of all both Log4J and SLF4J provide very flexible way of controlling what level of logging gets printed (trace, debug, warning, info, error, fatal) and you can have configuration file that may or may not be exposed to your end user where you can control with great flexibility what levels are allowed or blocked and for which packages. Please refer to respective reference to see how its done. Also, there is an Open Source java library called MgntUtils that provides a Utility that can extract exception stacktrace as a string and filter it smartly based on user provided package prefix. it shortens the stacktrace significantly but leaves the relevant part in which makes your logs shorted and your stacktrace by far better readable. Here is the link to the article about this library which provides links to Maven Central and github: [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=mp-reader-card). The library comes with well-written javadoc and source code